PLAB 2 Visa Sponsor
I'd be traveling to the UK  for my Plab 2 exams via a visit visa and my  father is my sponsor.
Can he just send the  sponsorship money to my bank account with appropriate description and if yes,how long does the money have the be in my account before application and what sponsor documents do I need to get?

It is usually much better if your father submits his own financial statements.

Your father would need to provide his bank statements for the 6 months preceding your application and proof of the source of the funds eg his pay slips, employment contract. There’s some good information on common reasons for PLAB refusals in this answer

You might alos review this question and answer.
